# Can't recover full KeyPair from PrivateKey saved as string

Tags: java, private-key

I generated a secp256k1 KeyPair and saved the private key to a file as Base58 and Base64.

I thought perhaps it was a standard PrivateKey string from:

```
   Base64.encode(privateKey.getEncoded())
```

The Base58 string is 87 characters long.
The Base64 string is 88 characters long.

I believe I'm able to get the PrivateKey, ECPrivateKey, and ECPublicKey from this:

```
 byte[] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.decode(known64);
 KeyFactory kecFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
 PrivateKey privateKeyNative = kecFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes));
 ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKeyNative = (ECPrivateKey) privateKeyNative;
 ECPublicKey ecPublicKeyNative = getPublicKey(ecPrivateKeyNative);
```

It works without error, however I need to get back to the full KeyPair. I've tried all sorts of looking online and just seem to be hitting a wall.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is getPublicKey?

Comment: It's just deriving the ECPublicKey from the ECPrivateKey (not the PublicKey that I think I need to get back to a KeyPair).